# Call from Java to c++ and then from the same c++ method make a call to java method

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

The following code can invoke a C++ method from Java.

**JNITest.java**

```
public class JNITest  {
    static {
        System.load("D:\\gagan docs\\TestJava\\Example.dll");
    }

    public native int intMethod(int n);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JNITest jnitest = new JNITest();
        int square=jnitest.intMethod(5);
        System.out.println("HelloWorld");
        System.out.println("From init method"+square);
    }

}
```

**Example.cpp**

```
#include "JNITest.h"
#include<string.h>
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_JNITest_intMethod(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jint num)
{
    return num*num;
}
```

But when I try to call a java method from the above CPP using the following, the JVM crashes.

I have also tried with createJavaVM method to create JVM, but it crashed.

**Example.cpp**

```
#include "JNITest.h"
#include<string.h>
static JavaVM *jvm = NULL
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_JNITest_intMethod(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jint num) 
{
    JNIEnv* jenv;
    int res = jvm->AttachCurrentThread((void **)&jenv, NULL);
    return num*num;
}
```

I am using Linux(64 bit)machine and JDK 64 bit(Java 1.6).

I want to make a complete flow from Java -> C++ -> Java. Any information on this issue will be very useful.

Comment: You don't even have a Java VM running?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#wp16660

Comment: How are you calling the java method from C++? (code please)

Comment: You don't need to create a new JVM if you're calling a `native` method from Java already. An example use case of `createJavaVM()` would be making a `.exe` wrapper around a Java program, not providing native methods.

Answer (score 1):

Calling Java from C++ is a (relatively) simple matter of:

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_JNITest_intMethod(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jint num)
{
    jint x = (env)->CallIntMethod(obj, method_id);
    // or, (env)->CallVoidMethod(obj, voidMethod, ...), etc.
}
```

This assumes the class of your `jobject` has the method identified by `jmethodID`. Obtaining the `jmethodID` is simple too:

```
jclass class_inst = (env)->FindClass("pkg/to/my/stuff/Class");
jmethodID method_id = (env)->GetMethodId(class_inst, "methodName", "()I");
```

Getting the method you want to call for a particular class is probably your most challenging task, but not at all hard once you have a good grasp of fundamentals.

For a nice example (disclaimer: I'm the example's author), see [inotify-interface.cpp](https://bitbucket.org/nbargnesi/inotify-java/src/27510bee4b9a/src/cpp/inotify-interface.cpp?at=default).

Note also, you probably **aren't** interested in calling [AttachCurrentThread](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.oracle.com%2Fjavase%2F1.5.0%2Fdocs%2Fguide%2Fjni%2Fspec%2Finvocation.html&ei=A1B4UMOCMIbh0wG21YDYAw&usg=AFQjCNH_3oBjMAoMcKWytYZLlsph7NcmTA&cad=rja)!

Comment: Thanks isengrab.. i tried the thins suggested by you, it works fine without creating jvm inside JNIEXPORT..

Comment: Thanks all and thanks isengrab.. i tried the things suggested by you above, it works fine without creating jvm inside JNIEXPORT.. But if i want to create a jvm completely outside the JNIEXPORT environment..i.e. I am trying to create a jvm completely inside only cpp using createJavaVM or AttachCurrentThread or AttachCurrentThreadAsDaemon according to the jdk version..  But all these methods returns zero.. And GetCreatedJavaVM also returns zero.. I am using jdk1.6 on Linux 64 bit machine..  Any suggestion will be very helpful..